# Copying a local file from Windows to a remote server using scp with name or service not known error

Tags: ssh, copy, scp

I am trying to copy files from the local windows 10 laptop to the remote server using SCP.
After connecting to the server, I used the server's command prompt to run the following commands.

```
scp -r C:/CVPR2022_1st/NAFNet/ user@host: /home/folder1/folder2
scp -r C:\CVPR2022_1st\NAFNet\ user@host: /home/folder1/folder2
```

Both commands return the same error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname c: Name or service not known
```

Comment: You can't run this SCP command from the remote server .. You need to run it from your Windows laptop machine.  And Windows doesn't have a native way to do this .. But it can be done if you have [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html)

Comment: Once PuTTY is installed you'll have to use "Putty SCP" -- It looks like: `pscp -scp [LOCAL FILE] user@host: /remote directory`